# Windows 10 start menu not calculating simple math expressions

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, start-menu, calculator

I have a couple of computers with windows 10 and on most of them typing a simple expression like 12*5 results in displaying the calculator and I find this extremely helpful. Look at screenshot #1

However one of my computers (which previously had windows 7 and I upgraded it to windows 10) does not do that - see screenshot #2

How can I fix this and make this computer behave like the rest?

[image: screenshot #1] [image: screenshot #2]

Answer (score 0):

But it's not solving the equation. It's posting it to the Bing browser (similar to how google can do math), and then rendering the webpage in the start menu.

Why not just use the Calculator application? That's what it's for.

Comment: Not what I asked. I can use my phone, or the calculator sitting on my desk, or push my brain a bit to calculate it myself without the need of a computer. I have many options, but it's so much more convenient to use the start menu.

Compare the number of clicks and keypresses required to open a calculator, then close it vs pressing the windows button, typing 12*5 then press esc or windows button again to hide it. VS pressing win, typing calc, then 12*5 then closing it via Alt+F4.

I like to use the start menu, thank you. 

PS: MacOS does the same when you open spotlight.

Comment: Yes I use this a lot, but lately is not working in my laptop, I think its because I disabed web results in start menu, cannot imagine why would windows need to go out to the internet to be able to calculate 2+2 while having everything it needs locally. available :s,

Comment: this stopped working in my pc too, I have tried enabling web search in start menu by registry settings and policies but still calculations will not work, had to get used to using powertoys run